# Custom Comparator

Tags: java, list, sorting, comparator

Given the following list: `"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"`

I need a comparator that does the following sorting:

- specify a certain element (e.g. `"D"`)
- start with the element
- followed by all following elements of the original list in the original order
- followed by all preceding elements of the original list in the original order

The result would be: `"D", "E", "F", "G", "A", "B", "C"`

---

Please be aware that I know that I could just do stuff similar to the following:

```
List<String> following = myList.subList(myList.indexOf("D") + 1, myList.size());
List<String> preceding = myList.subList(0, myList.indexOf("D"));
List<String> newList = Stream.of(Collections.singletonList("D"), following, preceding)
                       .flatMap(List::stream)
                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**In this question I explicitly mean a `Comparator` implementation.**

---

It is clear that it will have to have the list & element as a parameter, I am just not clear about the comparison algorithm itself:

```
private static class MyComparator<T> implements Comparator<T> {

  private final List<T> list;
  private final T element;

  private MyComparator(List<T> list, T element) {
    this.list = list;
    this.element = element;
  }

  @Override
  public int compare(T o1, T o2) {
    // Not clear
  }
}
```

Comment: The int should be `0` if there are identical, `negative` if `o1` is before `o2` and `positive` for the opposite (to be confirmed, might be the opposite). But with `T` not extending anything, you have only what `Object` provide, so not much to compare. Well this is explain in [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

Comment: I am clear about how a comparator works, I am just not clear about how to produce those numbers here for the given sorting algorithm :)

Comment: Are you sure that your design is correct? It looks to me that you would need a tree-based data structure.

Comment: "I need a comparator that does the following sorting" => This sentence is the first point of your confusion. A comparator only compares two elements. It does not do any sorting, although it helps a sorting algorithm to get the "correct" sort order. In fact, this question is a bit unclear to me. Maybe you could show us how you would use such a comparator?

Comment: Well, since the comparator is used to "bubble sort" the list by comparing every element with the next one, this will not be easy... I guess that if you give the comparator the "element" that should change the logic, it could be possible but I don't believe it would worth it

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. To clear things up: the place this sorting is needed could of course use the other approach I wrote. The comparator implementation is just out of personal interest and convenience use cases, e.g. in streams.

Comment: Just a question, you said "followed by all following elements of the original list in the original order" because the list is already ordered ? Or even if it is not order, this is still the following elements that should be put ? If this is the last, well my answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want :

```
class ImposedOrder<T> implements Comparator<T> {

    private final List<T> list;
    private final int startIndex;

    ImposedOrder(List<T> list, T startElement) {
        this.list = new ArrayList<>(list);
        this.startIndex = list.indexOf(startElement);
        if (startIndex < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(T t1, T t2) {
        int t1Index = list.indexOf(t1);
        int t2Index = list.indexOf(t2);
        return Integer.compare(adjust(t1Index), adjust(t2Index));
    }

    private int adjust(int rawIndex) {
        if (rawIndex >= startIndex) {
            return rawIndex;
        }
        return rawIndex + list.size();
    }
}
```

Some extra validation may be in order to avoid an imposed order list with duplicates.

The linear search, using `indexOf` doesn't give you a great performance, but for a small order list it may suffice. Otherwise, rather than saving a copy of the imposed order list, you could map elements to their adjusted index in the Comparator's constructor.

Like this :

```
class ImposedOrder<T> implements Comparator<T> {

    private final Map<T, Integer> map;
    private final int startIndex;

    ImposedOrder(List<T> list, T startElement) {
        this.startIndex = list.indexOf(startElement);
        if (startIndex < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        this.map = IntStream.range(0, list.size())
                .boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        list::get,
                        i -> adjust(startIndex, list.size(), i)
                ));
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(T t1, T t2) {
        Integer t1Index = map.get(t1);
        Integer t2Index = map.get(t2);
        return t1Index.compareTo(t2Index);
    }

    private static int adjust(int startIndex, int size, int rawIndex) {
        if (rawIndex >= startIndex) {
            return rawIndex;
        }
        return rawIndex + size;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if I got the question right you what to do `Collections.sort(myList, myComparator);`

then I can suggest you using a defined collator:

```
List<String> myList = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G");
System.out.println(myList);
String rules = "< d,D < e,E < f,F < g,G < a,A < b,B < c,C";

RuleBasedCollator ruleBasedCollator = new RuleBasedCollator(rules);
Collections.sort(myList, ruleBasedCollator);
System.out.println(myList);
```

the rule here is `"< d,D < e,E < f,F < g,G < a,A < b,B < c,C"` which means which chars have a higher weight than others... the rest is as usual a sorting method

the output

> [A, B, C, D, E, F, G]
>
> [D, E, F, G, A, B, C]

Comment: I think this is not what asked

Comment: @nilesh you are right, now the answer is corrected!

Comment: Not the correct output : `"D", "E", "F", "G", "A", "B", "C"`, everything after the "D" should follow it. But I didn't knew the `Collator`, thanks !

Comment: Not exactly what I expected, but the `RuleBasedCollator` is interesting, did not know about this one! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make much sense to use a `Comparator` here, since it would be very inefficient (since you would have to locate the indices of the 2 compared elements in the original list, which would cause each comparison to require linear time).

And it may fail anyway if the list contains duplicates.

However, since you asked, something like this may work:

```
public int compare(T o1, T o2) {
    if (o1.equals(o2)
        return true;
    int i1 = list.indexOf(o1);
    int i2 = list.indexOf(o2);
    int ie = list.indexOf(element); // this can be done in the constructor of the Comparator
    // now you have to check whether i1 and i2 are smaller than or larger than
    // ie, and based on that determine which of the corresponding elements should come
    // first
}
```

or, simply call

```
Collections.rotate(list,list.size() - list.indexOf(element));
```

Answer (score 0):

I knew it was possible, but it is messy ... **and unsafe**

The idea to push the first block to the end is to add a `String` to force those value to be bigger. That way, "A" is bigger than "G" if it looks like "ZA" when it is compare with.

```
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(new String[]{ "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"});
    final String split = "D";
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>(){
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            //Prepend with a big String value (like "ZZZZ") if it is before the value `split`.
            if(o1.compareTo(split) < 0)
                o1 = "ZZZZ" + o1;
            if(o2.compareTo(split) < 0)
                o2 = "ZZZZ" + o2;

            return o1.compareTo(o2); //then compare
        }
    });

    System.out.println(list);
```

> [D, E, F, A, B, C]

This is not safe since this could be complicate to prepend with a safe value that will be bigger, I thought about using `Character.MAX_VALUE` but I am not sure this would be safer. Well, using the `split` value itself could be way simpler ..

Comment: I think you will get some trouble if the generic type is `MyClass` which especially does not overwrite `toString`

Comment: @StefanWarminski I will not, I used a `String` since the question used it for the `List`. For other `Class`. The same logic could be add with some genericity but this would still need an interface to get a typed value to compare. If you use `toString`, this would work to but the output will depends on the method itself, that could not be overriden, so it would be ordered based on the name of the class and the hashcode (I think it is basicly the output)

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare the indexes of the elements.

```
private static class MyComparator<T> implements Comparator<T> {

    private final List<T> list;
    private final int elementIndex;

    private MyComparator(List<T> list, T element) {
        // keep original order
        this.list = new ArrayList<>(list);
        this.elementIndex = list.indexOf(element);
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(T o1, T o2) {
        int i1 = list.indexOf(o1);
        int i2 = list.indexOf(o2);
        if (i1 == elementIndex) {
            // "shift" first element left
            return -1;
        } else if (i2 == elementIndex) {
            // "shift" secont element left
            return 1;
        }
        boolean left1 = i1 < elementIndex;
        boolean left2 = i2 < elementIndex;
        if (left1 != left2) {
            // different part
            return i2 - elementIndex;
        } else {
            // same part
            return i1 - i2;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to compare weights of the elements based on the original indexes in the list - if index of current element >= index of the specified certain element (e.g. "D"), then index in the new list should be moved to the left, index of "D" is exactly the required offset.

```
int weightO1 = list.indexOf(o1) - list.indexOf(element);
```

in the opposite case (list.indexOf(o1) < list.indexOf(element)) the calculation of the weight should move element to the right, e.g. it could be

```
int weightO1 = list.indexOf(o1) + list.size();
```

I'd incapsulate calculation of weight in local method:

```
   int weight (T o) {
    return int weight = list.indexOf(o) < list.indexOf(element) ? list.indexOf(o) + list.size() : list.indexOf(o) - list.indexOf(element);
   }
```

so the implementation of compare method would be like:

```
@Override
  public int compare(T o1, T o2) {
     return weight(o1) - weight(o2); 
  }
```